# ¿Como buscar de un datagridview a otro datagridview que esta en otro form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un `DataGridView` en un **formulario 1**, este se carga de datos desde una `base de datos` en `Sql`, en ese formulario tengo un botón para abrir otro **formulario 2** donde esta otro `DataGridView` que tiene los mismos datos de mi **formulario 1**. Mi pregunta es: ¿Como buscar los datos desde mi **formulario 2**
y al seleccionar la fila y apretar un botón, se me cierre el **formulario 2** y me seleccione la fila en mi **formulario 1** donde se encuentran esos datos?.

Trabajo en 3 Capas:
Procedimiento Almacenado:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[sp_MostrarProductos]
as
select IdProducto, NombreProd, ReferProd,DescripProd, MedidasProd.IdMedidas,MedidasProd.NombreMedidas,
StockProd, CostoProd,Precio1Prod,Precio2Prod,Precio3Prod,Proveedor.IdProveedor, Proveedor.RazonSocial_Prov from Productos
INNER JOIN MedidasProd ON Productos.IdMedidasProd = MedidasProd.IdMedidas
INNER JOIN Proveedor ON Productos.IdProveedor = Proveedor.IdProveedor
```

Capa Datos:

```
public DataTable MostrarProductosGrid()
        {
            using(var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
            {
                conexion.Open();
                using(var comando = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                    comando.Connection = conexion;
                    comando.CommandText = "sp_MostrarProductos";
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader leerFilas = comando.ExecuteReader();
                    tabla.Load(leerFilas);
                    leerFilas.Close();
                    return tabla;
                }
            }
        }
```

Capa Negocio:

```
public DataTable RecogerDatosProd()
        {
            CD_Productos d_Productos = new CD_Productos();
            return dProductos.MostrarProductosGrid();
        }
```

Capa presentacion:

```
 private void GridProductos()
        {
            DModeloProductos mProductos = new DModeloProductos();
            dgvProductos.DataSource = mProductos.RecogerDatosProd();

        }
```

Formulario 1:

[image: Formulario 1]

Formulario 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existen varias opciones para lo que quieres, pero falta lo mas importante y es el código que ocupas para crear o "poblar" esas grillas, como las generas si son dinamicas o estaticas... Por favor añade el código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: @harifo Coloque como lo llamo, y mi procedimiento almacenado, lo llamo así desde ambos formularios

Comment: @Nathy no entiendo para que quieres tener dos formularios con la misma informacion y cuando vuelves atras quede seleccionada la fila que tocaste en el otro. De todos modos sobre los formularios puedes usar los eventos que tienen en la ventana de propiedades de visual studio. Cuanto toques el grid y veas sus propiedades ahi tendras los eventos disponibles.

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te puedo ayudar, te pongo un ejemplo con string, pero lo puedes adaptar para que retorne lo que necesites para seleccionar la fila deseada en el grid del formulario 1 (por ejemplo, rowindex, condiciones de búsqueda, etc...).

Condición previa: Abres el formulario 2 con showDialog (para esperar el resultado).

Entonces es sencillo:

1/ Crea una propiedad pública con lo que desees devolver en el formulario 2. Por ejemplo:

```
public string ValorARetornar {get;set;}
```

2/ En el evento en que cierres el formulario 2 establece el valor de esa propiedad, por ejemplo:

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  this.ValorARetornar = "Texto de ejemplo";
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
  this.Close();
}
```

3/ En el formulario 1 al llamar al formulario 2, simplemente recupera el valor así:

```
    var result = formulario2.ShowDialog();
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
     string valorRecuperado = formulario2.ValorARetornar ; 

     //Hacer algo con valor recuperado      
   }
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Doy por hecho que tienes un WinForm formulario1 y un Winform formulario2, cada uno de ellos con su DataGridview.

En el formulario2 añade a su datagridview el evento 'CellClick':

```
    /*De esta forma capturo el codigo que esta en la segunda columna del grid. */
    private void Cell_Click(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {  
            DataGridViewRow row = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string codigo = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            /*Cierro el formulario2 y llamo al formulario1 pasandole el codigo*/
            Form1 formulario1 = new Form1(codigo);
            formulario1.Show();
            this.Hide();
    }
```

En el formulario1 sobrecarga un constructor con el parametro a recibir el codigo:

```
string codigo = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.codigo = null;
    }

    public Form1(string codigo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         Aqui tu DataGridView debe llevar datos
        */

        if(codigo != null)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridForm1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == codigo)
                {
                    row.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Para acabar solo decirte que veo q estas aplicando algún patron, yo aqui NO he separado la logica de la vista lo dejo segun tus necesidades. Y por ultimo, solo un consejo,  decirte que tu peticion es un poco extraña porque tener en dos grids los mismos datos no tiene mucho sentido, a lo mejor debes repensar a donde quieres llegar.
Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por responder, tomaré en cuenta su consejo de tener dos grid con los mismo datos, lo quería usar como un buscador